# Getting unreachable statement error even though it reaches during run time in spring hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to catch exceptions which will occur during run time in spring hibernate below is hibernate code which inserts data into sql table but i want to catch certain exceptions but i am getting below

**error:**

> Unreachable catch block for JDBCConnectionException.

This exception is never thrown from the try statement body

```
  try
    {
       TokenBo tokenBo = (TokenBo)appContext.getBean("TokenBo");
       Token token = new Token();
       token.setFirstName(FirstName);
       tokenBo.save(token);
    }
    catch(JDBCConnectionException  e1) {}
```

Comment: If it is never thrown, don't try to catch it.

Comment: then what should i do to handle these exceptions and print custom messages

Comment: If they are not thrown, you should not even try to handle them.

Comment: they are thrown when the sql server is not started but try to access mysql

Comment: quoting the error message: "This exception is never thrown from the try statement body". Not there, they are not.

Comment: then i am getting org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException if dont have try catch

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88566/discussion-between-labeo-and-stultuske).

Answer (score 0):

`Runtime Exception & Error` are supposed to happen at run time (reporting that something went wrong when the program ran) and `ConstraintViolationException` is a runtime exception

The error you are getting is because `ConstraintViolationException` is never thrown from your code.

Why would you even want to catch `ConstraintViolationException`? This exception states that you failed to fulfill one of the DB constraints, which means you didn't have proper data check in place

Comment: i am not checking data because that is given by user and i will store in db if there is a primary key in a colon and a user given the one already exists then i should tell user about it that is why i need to catch that exception

Comment: @Label, sorry to say, but it's a bad practice Not to check user's data and populate it in DB. As a general rule, Input parameters for public method should always be checked. 

You will have to change your coding approach to avoid this error. This way you will save a trip to DB

Comment: ok i will do that can you give me solution to JDBCConnectionException

Comment: sorry for error message i was wrong i have edited it now please see and give solution

Comment: `appContext.getBean("TokenBo")` Does this code give you a JDBC Connection?

The rule is same, if your code doesn't throw an exception you are trying to catch, compiler will complain

Answer (score 0):

To avoid "chat" mode in commens:

The error message is pretty self-explanatory:

> This exception is never thrown from the try statement body

Remove the catch block for the ConstraintViolationException. Don't try to handle Exceptions that can not be thrown by your code.

If you remove this, and running your code causes a JDBCConnectionException, you'll need to tackle this problem, not creating another one to hide it.

If you need help to fix that issue, you'll have to provide more code/configuration/stacktrace/...

Comment: i am getting org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException  if i stop my sql server and run my code

Comment: how about: DON'T run your code with sql server shut down. It's the ConstraintViolationException that isn't thrown. I said nothing about the JDBCConnectionException. And you get that, because you shut down your server.

Comment: yeah i want to catch that exception  both the catch statements are having unreachable statement errors

Comment: sorry for error message i was wrong i have edited it now please see and give solution